# Unable to PUT when tunneling to a remote URL using localhost(127.0.0.1)

Tags: https, postman, ssh-tunnel

I wanted to do a GET on the following URL in Postman with Basic Authorization:

```
https://1.2.3.4:8338/accounts
```

Unfortunately I cannot connect directly to that server so I've tunneled through Jump server 5.6.7.8 using SSH Tunnel Manager and

```
ssh -N -p 22 username@5.6.7.8 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -L 127.0.0.1:8080:1.2.3.4:8338
```

That worked. I now want to create a container by doing a PUT to this URL using AWSV4 Authorization:

```
https://1.2.3.4/testcontainer
```

If I use the above tunner I get a 404 error. I've a feeling that my issue is that the tunnel is on port 8338 but my URL doesn't specify a port. I've tried leaving the port on 1.2.3.4 blank but it defaults to 0 and the tunnel doesn't work.

I then tried setting that port to 443(default HTTPS port). When I do that I get a SignatureDoesNotMatch error. I think that's because I set the AWSV4 authentication up on port 8338(it's a guess).

Finally I tried to setup AWSV4 authorization with port 443 but received a 403 error.

I'm not sure where to go now. Can anybody advise what I might have to do a PUT to the below URL using localhost?

```
https://1.2.3.4/testcontainer
```

---

UPDATE 2017-06-28

---

I got access to a server that can connect directly to 1.2.3.4 and decided to try using curl in the terminal. It wouldn't work as I need to use AWS v4 auth. When looking into this I came across s3curl. I've tried running the following:

```
./s3curl.pl --id personal -- -s -v -X PUT https://1.2.3.4/testcontainer -k
```

Still no luck. This is the output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 1.2.3.4...
* Connected to 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=T; L=A; O=B; CN=access01.b.com;       emailAddress=b@us.b.com
*    start date: 2017-06-04 08:05:04 GMT
*    expire date: 2018-06-05 08:25:00 GMT
*    issuer: C=US; ST=I; L=C; O=cc; CN=Manager CA; serialNumber=serialnumber
*    SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> PUT /testcontainer HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 1.2.3.4
> Accept: */*
> Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2017 13:23:01 +0000
> Authorization: AWS authoization
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2017 13:23:01 GMT
< X-Clv-Request-Id: requestid
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
* Server cc/3.1.0.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: cc/3.1.0.1
< X-Clv-S3-Version: 2.5
< x-amz-request-id: requestid
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Content-Length: 894
< 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Error>   <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. For more information, see REST Authentication and SOAP Authentication for details.</Message><Resource>/pctestcontainer1/</Resource><RequestId>bfb1bdf1-9d7a-4bc7-966a-a3a5e89498eb</RequestId><StringToSign>PUT


Wed, 28 Jun 2017 13:23:01 +0000
* Connection #0 to host 10.137.63.202 left intact
/pctestcontainer1</StringToSign><StringToSignBytes>80 85 84 10 10 10 87 101 100 44 32 50 56 32 74 117 110 32 50 48 49 55 32 49 51 58 50 51 58 48 49 32 43 48 48 48 48 10 47 112 99 116 101 115 116 99 111 110 116 97 105 110 101 114 49</StringToSignBytes><SignatureProvided>signature</SignatureProvided><AWSAccessKeyId>accesskey</AWSAccessKeyId><httpStatusCode>403</httpStatusCode></Error>root@utility:/tmp/cp/s3curl#
```

Does this mean anything to anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of investigation I found that I needed to include a "Host" key in my header and use the AWS V4 credentials I generated.

I can now do a PUT using a statement in Postman.

Comment: Thanks a ton man! I was stuck on this from months and wasn't able to use it from localhost :)